# Show that a subset of $C[0,1]$ is closed

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a question I my metric spaces course book I cannot solve:

Show that the following subset is closed in $C[0,1]$: $\{ f \in C[0,1] \mid f(a)=0 \textrm{ for all }a \in A \}$, where $C[0,1]$ is the space of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ with the sup metric and $A \subseteq [0,1]$.

Comment: It might be easier to show the complement is open.  You'll probably want to use the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact along the way.

Comment: i must confess that i think my answer is "higher level", but showing the complement of the set is open is far more direct for a beginner (and a more likely line of inquiry). hopefully you can work out both approaches :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see where the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact is necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: @dc2814 it's just so the $\sup$ norm is always defined, otherwise you have to restrict to the functions where it is defined

Comment: @exitingcorpse Ahh, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ was just one point, could you see why it's true? Can you see how this proves it for general $A$?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to approach this is to use the following characterization for closed sets.

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $B\subset X$. Then $B$ is closed in $X$ iff $B$ contains all of its limit points. $y$ is a limit point for $B$ if there is a sequence $\{b_n\}\subset B$ such that $b_n \to b$.

So suppose $g$ is a limit point of $B=\{f\in C[0,1] | f(a) = 0\; \forall a\in A\}$, and $\{g_n\} \subset B$ is a sequence such that $g_n \to g$, and let $a\in A$. That $g_n \to g$ just means that $g_n$ converges to $g$ uniformly. So if $g_n(a) = 0$, then what can you say about $g(a)$?

Answer (score -1):

First proof it taking $A$ as a singleton which is shown by someone else above then it is obvious because intersection of closed sets is closed.